Filtered PowerBI table views in Sharepoint embed
Filtered PowerBI table views in Sharepoint page embeds
I have a simple PowerBI file with pie charts to filter on a table. Is there a way to have different pre-filtered table views display on different sharepoint pages? i.e. on one page the table is filtered on "Product A" and other pages the table is filtered on "Product B" etc etc? I will have a seperate "master page" where users can see all data and filter themselves, but I need pre-filtered tables on different product pages.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: the url is:
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=8eb2fb12-73cd-4e8c-a3e9-94afd41295a2&filter=”Table dark”/”Car%20Make”%20eq%20%27“Ford”%27and%20“Table dark”/”Color” %20eq%20%27“Red”%27

Are you using the "Embed a report webpart" or are you adding an iframe to the page?

embedding a PowerBI web part

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
